# retrive firebase info to set button titles

Tags: ios

I am trying to retrieve information from firebase to set button titles which allow users to interact with the view in different ways. I am not sure about how to go about this so I will post some code in hopes someone understands.

```
    func fetchJobProgress() {
        let workerId = workerUser?.uid
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("workInProgress").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId").queryEqual(toValue: workerId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
                self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleConfirm), for: .touchUpInside)







        }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
func fetchJobProgress() {
        let workerId = workerUser?.uid
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    Database.database().reference().child("workInProgress").child(uid!).queryOrdered(byChild: "fromId").queryEqual(toValue: workerId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        for (_, valueDic) in dictionary {
            guard let dic = valueDic as? [String: Any] else {
                continue
            }
            guard let type = dic["type"] as? Int else {
                continue
            }

            if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.accepted.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
                self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleConfirm), for: .touchUpInside)

            } else if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.inProgress.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.setTitle("In Progress...", for: .normal)
                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                self.confirmButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleComplete), for: .touchUpInside)

            } else if type == userNotifications.NotificationType.confirmCompleted.rawValue {

                self.confirmButton.setTitle("Completed!", for: .normal)
                self.confirmButton.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
                self.confirmButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false


                          }

            break
        }





        }, withCancel: { (err) in
        print("attempting to load information")
        })

    }
```